# Spree version verification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I have just upgraded Spree from 1.3 to 2-0-stable. Is there any way to verify the Spree version. From either the front end or back end? We need to show the client it has been upgraded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use method:

```
Spree.version
```